# If then else conditions in order by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following fields:

- id
- discount_amount
- discount_expires_at

How can I query all of the records and order them by `discount_amount`, **but only if** the `discount_expires_at` is greater than the current time?

All rows must be included anyway, but they should appear first only if the discount has not expired as of now. If it has expired, then they must be sorted by id, descending

Comment: If `discount_expires_at` be _less_ than the current time, then how should the records be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use case expressions:

```
select *
from t
order by
    case when discount_expires_at > current_timestamp then 1 else 2 end,
    case when discount_expires_at > current_timestamp then discount_amount end desc,
    case when discount_expires_at > current_timestamp then null else id end desc
```

The expression `discount_expires_at > current_timestamp` condition will either be true or false/unknown; select the desired column based on these two possible outcomes.

Comment: This won't order the first set of rows, it will only list them before the other rows

Comment: Not from how I read the question

Comment: I would like to, include all rows. If 10 rows have active discounts ( not expired ), they must be in the first 10 positions, and their position must be decided by `discount_amount`. The remaining rows that do not have active discounts must come after the first 10, and they must be ordered by their ids

Comment: Everything is descending. I want the most discounted ones first, then the most recent ones. And also, what is the difference between this and Patrick's answer and which one is more performant

Comment: I've updated the answer. I am assuming that discount_amount and id are numeric and comparable.

Answer (score 2):

Order descending by a composite value, `(1, discount_amount)` if discount is still in effect or `(0, id)` if not. The first constant - 1 or 0 - makes expired discounts come after the active ones.

```sql
select * from the_table
order by 
 case
   when discount_expires_at > current_timestamp then (1, discount_amount)
   else (0, id)
 end desc;
```